# use where query depends on query on prisma

Tags: prisma

```
    const fictions = await client.fiction.findMany({
      where: {
        AND: [
          { genre: genres as string },
          { nationality: nationalities as string },
          {
            keywords: {
              some: {
                keyword: {
                  name: keywords?.toString().split(",").join(" | "),
                },
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      include: { ~~~
      },
      orderBy: {
        userFictionStat: {
          total: "asc",
        },
      },
    });
```

Hi, I'm new to prisma so stuck in createing api pages.

I want to filter my 'fictions' with multiple criteria
('genre' or 'nationality' or 'keywords').

The problem is that when 'genre' or 'nationality' or 'keywords' are 'undefined'(button unclicked), the result becomes 0.(because of the 'AND').

I can't find out how can I filter my fictions with given criteria(with clicked buttons, even if some buttons are unclicked).

Also, I'd like to know how can I sort my fictions using my queries.
(lik if i get query {sorting : totalpoint} I can sory by totalPoint, and if i get {sorting : title} then I can sort by title name.

If anyone could help, I would be very thank you.

Comment: Are you sure it is actually undefined? if your genres as undefined, then prisma will ignore it.

Comment: @SlothOverlord
Thank you, you're right. it's not 'undefined' it's '' actually, is there any solution if it's the case? I have no idea how to deal with this problem.

Comment: If `genres` can be undefined or false-y (including `''` or `""`) then you can do `typeof genres === "string" ? genres : undefined` as part of your filter. Same for `nationalities`

Comment: @SheaHunterBelsky Thank you so much. Problem solved by this `'nationality: (nationalities as string) || undefined'`. I was stupid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `genres` can be undefined or false-y (including `''` or `""`) then you can do `typeof genres === "string" ? genres : undefined` as part of your filter. Same for `nationalities`. That way you know you're passing a string which has meaningful content OR you are ignoring the filter.